Veracrypt boot lock bricked machine?
My veracrypt has a hard drive boot lock. Unfortunately I've lost the password.
I don't care about the data on the PC, I just want my computer back. Meaning I don't mind resetting it.
When I power the machine down by holding the power button for 30s+ it still goes into boot lock.
I've tried inserting the rescue disc.
I've tried hitting the escape key to boot to BIOS.
Both to no avail.
Please help me. I don't like bricked machines.  Veracrypt forums are dead

Do you mean you cannot enter BIOS? If so, that has nothing to do with encryption. At the worst, removing the SSD or HDD should let you get to BIOS... and if not, BIOS is password protected, and you're out of luck.

correct. I cannot enter the bios because veracrypt has a feature where you can encrypt the entire drive. So therefore the pc first boots to a lock screen with a blue password box (similar to a bios password box). Someone said if i take it to a pc place they can remove the ssd or the pin to reset the bios. Im not sure any help is appreciated.

Pleas take a photo of the lock screen.  Its not clear whether you are talking about a bios password or veracrypt password.

@user580405, again remove the drive. If you still cannot enter BIOS, then BIOS is locked or damaged. Nothing to do with Veracrypt. Without BIOS password, you have a boat anchor (or papeer weigh, if too light for that function), not a PC.
